# Maximising probability of a given dice roll

Tags: probability, optimization

This is a problem from a Cambridge Example Sheet, which can be found [here](https://dec41.user.srcf.net/notes/IA_L/probability_eg.pdf).

#### Problem

Suppose a die is rolled $n$ times. Show that the probability of a roll of $i$ appearing $k_i$ times, $i = 1, \cdots, 6$ is
$$
\phi (k_1, \cdots, k_6) = \frac{n!}{k_1! \cdots k_6!} \frac{1}{6^n}.
$$

The expected value of the total of $n$ rolls is $3.5n$. Suppose $\sum_i{ik_i} = \rho n, 1 \le \rho \le 6$, and $k_i = np_i$. Use Stirling's formula to show that subject to these constraints, $\phi$ is maximised by choosing the $p_i$ as nonnegative numbers that solve the optimisation problem

$$
\max_{p_1, \cdots, p_6} - \sum_i p_i \log p_i, \text{ subject to } \sum_i p_i = 1, \text{ and } \sum_i{ip_i} = \rho.
$$

#### My approach

I approached the second part by, after applying Stirling's approximation, trying to ignore terms that depended only on $n$ and not on $p_i$, but it did not work, as an additional dependency on $\sum_i \log{p_i}$ still lingers. I also could not think of any way of using the constraint $\sum_i i p_i = \rho$.